# What blogs or articles online should I read to get started with quantitative finance?

Tags: learning, big-list

I want to start learning quantitative finance, what articles or blogs should I look at to start?

Also see the Related Question on [Quantitative Finance Books](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-good-technical-and-non-technical-books-for-a-math-lover-to-get-in-t)

Comment: This is another extremely general question.  Can you specify further what your interest is in "quantitative finance"?

Comment: I edited it to restrict to blogs because this question will come up over and over again, and you'll need a canonical place to send people. It's not a super question, but it will serve as a duplicate for many more future questions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to close this as "off topic"... This is intended to be a site for practicing quants, none of whom would ask a broad general question like this. It's important that when we come out of private beta, we have a REAL community of quants, and general, non-expert questions like this don't help. Later when the site is doing well it'll be fine to ask non-expert questions but for the private beta, please stick to real questions in quantitative finance, not surveys and polls.

Comment: See my further comments at http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4/

Comment: Here is a good site to start. I would also look up Wilmott

Comment: A good list is available at: thefinancialengineer.net/resources/reading-list

Answer (score 9):

Second Joshi guide but yout you can do better than that.

We have a list for all level, some of them are free to download (just like Joshi), others are books and websites that for beginner level

http://www.quantnet.com/master-reading-list-for-quants/

As for websites and blogs, there are only a handful of them out there (this is a niche field after all).

I run http://www.quantnet.com and I'm a member on http://wilmott.com as well as http://nuclearphynance.com. The Quant Finance group on LinkedIn is another popular destination.

Every site has a different flavor and attracts a fairly different audience. You have to sample them all, see the kind of questions asked there, the kind of members and how they answer.

**WARNING**: some sites are not very newbies friendly as they carter to the working professionals. As I said, it will take time to learn the in and out of each site.

Comment: Another such list is available at: http://thefinancialengineer.net/resources/reading-list/

Answer (score 5):

[Wilmott](http://www.wilmott.com/) and [NuclearPhynance](http://www.nuclearphynance.com/) are two fairly popular forums, although [quant.stackexchange.com](http://quant.stackexchange.com) will hopefully serve as a better resource in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I like this site http://quant.ly/

Answer (score 3):

Mark Joshi's advice - http://www.markjoshi.com/downloads/advice.pdf (On becoming a quant)

It's quite useful to get some insight into sorts of quantitative analysts, their repsonsibilites, type of companies, requirements for interviews etc ... just a great article to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

[Bionic Turtle's](http://www.bionicturtle.com/forum/) forums aren't bad. Some of it is aimed at the FRM (Financial Risk Manager) exam, but there's also a [section dedicated to Quant Finance](http://www.bionicturtle.com/forum/viewforum/5/).