# What books should any quantitative portfolio manager or risk manager have as reference?

Tags: risk-management, portfolio-management, reference-request

I'm interested to know what are the critical reference texts you rely on for portfolio or risk management? I mean those texts that you come back to because they are chock full of insight and know-how. For example:

Bernd Scherer - Portfolio Construction and Risk Budgeting (2005)

Grinold and Kahn - Active Portfolio Management (2002)

Meucci - Risk and Asset Allocation (2010)

Glasserman - Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering (2003)

John Cochrane - Asset Pricing (2005)

Gregory Connor - Portfolio Risk Analysis (2010)

Ruey Tsay - Analysis of Financial Time Series

Friedman - Elements of Statistical Learning

Geweke - Contemporary Bayesian Econometrics and Statistics

Comment: We've closed survey-style book recommendations plenty of times here and on other SE sites.

Answer (score 7):

Hull - Options, Futures and other Derivatives.

Comment: The best starter book for finance.

Answer (score 4):

Luenberger - Investment Science (1997)

Answer (score 3):

I think that one is also pretty well-known:

NcNeil, Frei, Embrechts  - [Quantitative Risk Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691122555)

Paul Wilmott - [Frequently Asked Questions in Quantitative Finance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470748753)

Answer (score 3):

I love Carol Alexander's [Market Risk Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470997990)!