# Which book would you recommend for beginners in Quantitative Finance?

Tags: finance-mathematics, quantitative, statistical-finance, books

I have a normal high school level of mathematics including some statistics and find the world of Quantitative Finance both alien and invigorating at the same time so, would like to learn more.

What book recommendations would people suggest for me to take me from lets say beginner to advanced including stochastic calculus and Ito's lemma etc. Ideally, a maths reminder book to start me off as lets say a number of years have passed since I was at high school :-)

I'm thinking less theoretical, interesting and easy reading if at all possible.

Comment: Hi Andrew, this site is dedicated to Quantitative Finance professionals and academics, and this question is far too broad and basic to be considered on-topic, see [help-center/on-topic]. Note that there is a huge selection good articles [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/recommendations-for-books-to-understand-the-math-in-quantitative-finance-papers).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is really hard (nearly impossible) to pursue a career in quantitative finance provided you only have high school level of math knowledge. I am sorry to say so.

College level math major courses would be helpful for you now. Try to learn calculus series and linear algebra would be your initial step.

Comment: OTOH perhaps Ito's Lemma is not as central to Finance as you believe. A lot of models are discrete time models (like the Binomial Model) that don't use Ito at all and you could certainly understand and program those...